# PDO bindParam not working in IN binding for sql query

Tags: php

I'm trying to get some `videos` according to some attributes (`age`, `year`, `countries`). For some reason, even though I'm binding parameters to the query properly and have specified the query properly (`u.country NOT IN ($countries_count)`), I still get results for the `country = U.S.A`. Is there something work with my `bindParam`. Please Help.

```
<?php
    $parameters = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $age = $parameters["age"];
    $year = $parameters["year"];
    $countries = sizeof($parameters["countries"]) == 0 ? array("0") : $parameters["countries"];
    $countries_count = implode(",", array_fill(0, sizeof($countries), "?"));

    $sql = "SELECT
                v.title, u.name 
            FROM 
                video AS v JOIN user AS u ON v.id_user = u.id 
            WHERE 
                u.age <= ? AND YEAR(v.upload_date) >= ? AND 
                u.country NOT IN ($countries_count);";

    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data_base", "root", "");
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(1, $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(2, $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    foreach ($countries as $k => $x) {
        $statement->bindParam($k+3, $x, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $statement->execute();
    echo json_encode($statement->fetchAll());
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are binding all the `IN` parameters to the same variable (`$x`) so they all end up with the same value. You can work around that by either changing to `bindValue` or by binding to the actual array value I.e.

```
$statement->bindParam($k+3, $countries[$k], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: $x is being assigned in the foreach loop... so it should be the same as $countries[$k]

Comment: @TimMorton yes, it's value is the same (which is why swapping to `bindValue` will work) but `bindParam` forms a link to the *variable*, so at the end of the loop, all the bound parameters will point to the same thing, and all get the same value.

Comment: Wow, it worked. Though I don't understand why my code in the question doesn't work. `$x` should have the exact same value as `$countries[$k]`.

Comment: @Aman see my previous comment to Tim Morton. `bindParam` forms a link to the variable, so *all* your parameters are bound to `$x`, and when you execute the query it has the last value in the `countries` array, meaning you are effectively ignoring the other vaues in the array.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for explaining.  Reference instead of value...  I completely missed any clues pointing to that.

Answer (score 1):

Change bindParam to bindValue

If you want to use bindParam, change your sql to

```
u.age <= :age and
YEAR(v.upload_date) >= :year
...
```

Then bind param:

```
->bindParam(':age', $age)
->bindParam(':year', $year)
```

Comment: What About for the `IN` statement?

Comment: Cannot use bindParam with IN clause. Can use bindValue instead or inject in sql

u.country NOT IN ('" . implode("','", $countries) . "')